# Norm of a matrix function of a vector $x$

Tags: matrices, norms

I have a matrix $$A(x) = \frac{-1}{(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}xx^T + \frac{1}{(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}I$$ I see that $$\|A(x)\|_2 \le 1 \ \forall x$$

But is $\|A(x)\| \le 1$ in general $\forall x$ and if so, how to show this?.

---

Yes indeed [Iosif Pinelis] and [Denis Serre], i switched the order. Yes, I am referring to operator norm. Is it correct that $\|A(x)\| \le 1 \forall x$?

Comment: What norms are you using?

Comment: Are you sure of the formula ? This matrix sounds familiar to me, but only if the exponents $1/2$ and $3/2$ are exchanged.

Comment: It's of course false as written (compare Denis's comment) because it doesn't scale right: $\langle x, A(\lambda x) x\rangle \simeq -\lambda \|x\|$ as $\lambda\to\infty$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$As noted by [Denis Serre](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464572/norm-of-a-matrix-of-vector-x#comment1206638_464572) and [Christian Remling](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464572/norm-of-a-matrix-of-vector-x/464603#comment1206714_464572), the exponents $1/2$ and $3/2$ must be interchanged -- otherwise, $\|A(x)\|_2\to\infty$ if $x=tu$, $u$ is a fixed unit vector, and $t\to\infty$.

So, the meaningful re-interpretation of the question is as follows:

> Let
> $$A(x) := \frac{-xx^T}{(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{I}{(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{1/2}}$$
> for $x\in\R^n$. Is it true that $\|A(x)\|\le1$ for all $x\in\R^n$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is an [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms)?

The answer to this question is no, even if the same norm is used on the domain and the co-domain of the linear operator corresponding to the matrix $A(x)$. (If different norms are allowed to be used for the domain and the co-domain, then the no answer is quite obvious.)

For instance, suppose that $n=5$, $\|\cdot\|$ is the [operator norm induced by the $\ell^\infty$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_p-norms) on $\R^5$, $x=\frac1{1000}(160, 159, 197, -159, -160)$, and $y=(1, 1, -1, -1, -1)$. Then $\|y\|_\infty=1$ but
$$\|A(x)\|\ge\|A(x)y\|_\infty=1.0076\ldots>1.$$

---

However, since $0\le xx^T\le\|x\|_2^2\,I$, we have $0\le(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{-3/2}\,I\le A(x)\le(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{-1/2}\,I$ and hence
$\|A(x)\|_2\le(1+\|x\|_2^2)^{-1/2}\le1$, for all $x\in\R^n$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : What do you mean by the $\|\cdot\|_{2,2}$ norm?

Comment: $\|A\|_{2,2}=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$

Comment: Ah, I see. I think this is what the OP denoted simply by $\|\cdot\|_2$, with the $\cdot$ standing for a matrix. This norm was considered in the last paragraph of my answer, and apparently concerning this case the OP said "I see that [...]". So, it does not appear to me that the question was about $\|\cdot\|_{2,2}$.

Comment: Yes indeed [Iosif Pinelis] and [Denis Serre], i switched the order. Yes, I am referring to operator norm. Is it correct that $\|A(x)\| \le 1 \forall x$?

Comment: @Shoeb : Again, your question has now been [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464603/36721) (negatively). Have you seen and read this answer?

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Shoeb : Does this answer fully (even if negatively) answer your question? If so, then [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) may be relevant.